# NextJS - Framer-Motion page transition doesn't fire

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

for some reason my NextJS page transition with framer-motion doesn't seem to work. I followed many tutorials and did a lot of research and it still doesn't work. Here's my `_app.tsx` code.

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/ui.css'
import '../fonts/define.css'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Layout from '../layouts/dashboard'
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return <main>
      <Sidebar/>
      <AnimatePresence>
        <motion.div initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{opacity: 1}} exit={{opacity: 0}} className="content">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </main>
}

export default App
```

When I switch between routes the transition just doesn't fire. It only fades in on initial load, then `opacity: 1` style is applied to `.content` div and that's it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add `key` attribute to the `<motion.div>` div. Read more here https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/#unmount-animations